# как через оператор NOT IN вывести список названий товаров, которые не поставлялись одним из поставщиков

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите, как из запроса вывести названия всех товаров и убрать те, которые поставлялись поставщиком «IDT».

```
SELECT 
    product, supplier
FROM 
    products,
    suppliers
WHERE 
    suppliers.id = (SELECT 
            id
        FROM 
            suppliers
        WHERE
            supplier =  'IDT');
```

Comment: я написал запрос который выводит товары которые поставлял поставщик IDT. не могу разобраться куда вставить NOT IN чтоб он убрал этого поставщика, и вывел всех остальных

Comment: а) какова структура таблиц? б) приведите пример данных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так я думаю

```sql
SELECT 
    product
FROM 
    products
WHERE 
    supplier NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            id
        FROM 
            suppliers
        WHERE 
            supplier = 'IDT'
    );
```

Comment: все равно в списке появляется данный поставщик

Comment: Ну тогда в базе показывайте базу данных, скорее всего там ошибка

Comment: добавил фото с базой

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо большое