# Написать SQL запрос с использованием подзапросов

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

есть запрос

1. Список названий поставщиков, которые в 2016 году поставили товаров на сумму больше, чем поставщик «IDT».

при попытке вывести всех кроме IDT выдает ошибку. что не так в коде кто может помочь

```
SELECT 
suppliers.supplier, A.action_sum
FROM suppliers 
INNER JOIN (SELECT supplier_id AS id, MAX(price * qty) AS action_sum 
FROM actions NOT IN ( SELECT supplier FROM suppliers WHERE supplier = 'IDT' and Year(action_date) = 2016;
```

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1503100/178576)?

Comment: нет, другое задание , то сделал. там товары были а здесь сумму больше вывести

Comment: *что не так в коде* Абсолютно всё... `.. A.action_sum ..` - это что за зверёк? Вот это как понимать: `.. FROM actions NOT IN ..`? Ой, да элементарно баланс скобок проверить - и то не сойдётся...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не совсем удобно без описания таблиц, но напрашивается (в учебных целях, как я понимаю), запрос с HAVING:

```
select supplier_id, supplier, sum(price*qty) summ 
from actions 
inner join suppliers on suppliers.id=supplier_id 
    where Year(action_date) = 2016 
group by supplier_id 
having summ > (
    select sum(price*qty) 
    from actions 
        where Year(action_date) = 2016 
            and supplier_id = (
                select id 
                from suppliers 
                    where supplier='IDT'
            )
);
```

Но не в учебных целях - такое себе

Comment: *но напрашивается (в учебных целях, как я понимаю), запрос с HAVING* В учебных целях следует писАть логически корректные запросы. А не абы что, зависящее от текущих настроек сессии.

Comment: шикарный комментарий. Большое спасибо. В виду скудоумия, не уловил, что некорректного, но ок.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, написал вчера запрос но чуть по другому)) ваш ответ оказался более понятным))

Comment: *В виду скудоумия, не уловил, что некорректного, но ок.* Incomplete grouping. Только расширение языка дозволяет выполнить запрос. Включите `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL Mode и убедитесь, что попытка выполнения запроса приводит к ошибке. Должно быть `GROUP BY supplier_id, supplier`. А если `suppliers.supplier` неуникально, то всё и вовсе плохо - самый внутренний подзапрос может вернуть несколько записей, с соответствующей ошибкой. Так что Ваш запрос - это куча ничем не обоснованных предположений, что "в учебных целях" крайне вредно.

Comment: @Akina "это куча ничем не обоснованных предположений" - MySQL 8.0.31 Community Server в докере, as is из официального образа. Угадать за автора вопроса структуру таблиц не берусь, о чем в ответе упомянуто, но предполагаю, что таблица suppliers все же имеет уникальные записи по id и, судя по вопросу, названию (что странно, но вряд ли бы иначе человека просили бы выбрать суммы поставок больше чем у поставщика с названием "IDT"?).

Comment: Ну приблизительно это я и имею в виду. Как рабочий код, если он не приводит к ошибкам - нормально. Если в будущем изменение версии и/или настроек сервера приведёт к проблемам - это не так уж и сложно будет поправить. Расширить выражение группировки, заменить равенство на WHERE IN... но вот именно в учебных целях такой запрос - не очень. Зачем учить плохому? этому он и сам научится, когда более-менее освоится.